# Web api Cross-Origin Request Blocked error when called Token service. Other services works

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api project separate and a simple UI project separate. To access web api in the UI project i have enabled `CORS` as below in `WebApiConfig.cs`

```
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:49567", "*", "*","*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
```

In `AccountController.cs` when `[Authorize]` is disabled i am able to access the  APIs from the UI html project page using ajax.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:51401/api/Account/UserInfo",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: VerifyResponse,
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        failure: ajaxCallFailed});
```

But when i want to enable `[Authorize]` to create token authentication by calling `/token`  first, the error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked:` repeats in the html.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:51401/Token",
    data: {
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val(),
        grant_type: 'password'
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: VerifyResponse,
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    failure: ajaxCallFailed
    });
```

My web.config in web api project now after the edit made after suggested by @arista_14

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>

    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol> 
  </system.webServer>
```

Now the error is :

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:51401/Token. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).[Learn More]
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:51401/Token. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem. Just put this code in web.config. It worked for me -

```
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: So both enableconfig in WebApiconfig.cs as well as web.config are required is it?

Comment: In web.config file. Try with any one. In my case this solution worked

Comment: @arista_14  modified the config with the changes but no luck yet. But the error message is slightly changed.. Modified my question with the changes. Is there anything else need to be mentioned in the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting cross-origin blocking happening is because of the ports being different. You specified this url in your CORS: http://localhost:**49567**

But then proceed to call it with this url: http://localhost:**51401**

Note the difference in ports. I actually had the same issue until I set my localhost port to something that doesn't change on a whim.

I also did the config another answer shows, which didn't work.

Comment: I do have 2 separate urls (2 separte projects a web api and a website). That is the reason the cors are enabled right?

Comment: try var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*","*");